# Is this an appropriate use of the Wilcoxon signed rank test

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

Please see data table:

```
"Year"    "%Chng"   "%Chng-1%" "Demand" "Diff"
2009      -13.5%    -14.5%     -5.5%    9.0%
2010      -13.3%    -14.3%     -6.4%    7.9%
2011        2.6%    1.6%        5.4%    3.8%
2012        7.5%    6.5%        3.2%    -3.3%
2013       -9.3%    -10.3%     -4.1%    6.2%
2014       -5.1%    -6.1%      -4.2%    1.9%
```

The raw data is %Chng and Demand. %Chng represents the year over year change in Google Insights relative search volume for Company A in a given year. Demand represents the actual year over year change in attendance at Company A. %Chng-1% simply represents 1% subtracted from %Chng. And, Diff is the difference between "%Chng-1%" and "Demand."

I used the Wilcoxon signed rank test and compared "Chng%-1%" and "Demand" to calculate W=17. I found a W table online for small 'n' that states that W=17 implies 95% confidence for a 1-tailed test for n=6. As a result, I conclude that if 2015 %Chng is +3.0%, actual attendance in 2015 will be greater than +2.0% with 95% confidence.

Is this a legitimate way to use the Wilcoxon signed rank test? 
If not, what's the problem?
If there is a problem, how big of a problem is it?
Since I only have one source for what W=17 signifies, can someone confirm that it signifies 95% confidence on a 1-tailed test for n=6?

Answer (score 1):

The size of N (6) is not large enough for the distribution of the Wilcoxon W statistic to form a normal distribution. Therefore, it is not possible to calculate an accurate p-value.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? The Wikipedia page on Wilcoxon signed rank test states that W can be referenced to a critical value from a reference table for n<10. If you believe Wikipedia is wrong, please explain. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe im not doing this correctly but i was just using a wilcoxon sign test calculator that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/signedranks/Default2.aspx

Comment: These are the links I was using: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#Test_procedure and
http://vassarstats.net/textbook/ch12a.html (scroll to the bottom for the Critical Values of W for Small Samples reference table)

Comment: @DaveRowan There are two ways to compute the p-value. There is a large sample approximation. There is also an exact p-value that can be computed by permutation test if the sample size is small enough.